# Insertar datos de una tabla en otra con una condicion mysqDe que otra forma podria h

Tags: mysql, select, mysql-workbench, insert

Buenas tengo el siguiente problema tengo dos tablas digamos que estas son tabla 1 y tabla 2.
La tabla 1 tiene la columna A, B, C, D
y tabla 2 tiene la columna A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I
Necesito insertar los datos B, C, D de la tabla 1 en la tabla 2 en las columnas F, G, H usando como Condicion que A=A

No puedo usar

> INSERT INTO tabla2 (F, G, H) SELECT B, C, D FROM tabla1;

ya que los datos estan desordenados por lo que al insertarse los datos quedarian mezclados

Es posible hacer una sentencia que cumpla con lo pedido, y si cumple de que forma seria?

Answer (score 0):

Creo que te puedes estar refiriendo a algo así:

```
INSERT INTO tabla2 (F, G, H)
  SELECT B, C, D FROM tabla1
    WHERE A IN (
      SELECT DISTINCT A
        FROM tabla2
    )
    ORDER BY A,B,C,D;
```

Aunque un ejemplo algo menos abstracto ayudaría a entender lo que realmente buscas y qué problema estás encontrando. Si concretas la pregunta, será un placer concretar la respuesta.

Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios.